# How to dynamically create providers at runtime with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

In my flutter app I am exploring a transition from the Provider package to Riverpod. The app is quite simple: it fetches a list of objects from a database, and allows the user to change these objects's characteristics. It is thus pretty similar to the [official TODO example app](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/tree/master/examples/todos).

I see however that such app does not provide an individual provider for each TODO item as I'd expect, but it rather declares a global provider the entire TODO list. I found such approach odd, as it requires that everytime a TODO item changes the entire list UI needs to be rebuilt (unless I am mistaken).

Reading through other examples, I see that all providers are always declared globally. Does this mean it is not possible with Riverpod to create new providers at runtime? (As in my case, from a list of objects returned by an API?)

I'm sorry if it is a trivial question, but I couldn't find any related example or documentation about this.

**EDIT:** I was mistaken indeed. The entire list is NOT rebuilt in its entirety. See answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is actually using a provider called `_currentTodo`:

```dart
final _currentTodo = Provider<Todo>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());
```

As you see, at the time of declaring this, there is no return value and instead we're throwing `UnimplementedError()`.

When it comes to populating a single `TodoItem`, we first wrap it with a `ProviderScope` widget. This allows us to override the value that `_currentTodo` provides with another value:

```dart
ProviderScope(
  overrides: [
    _currentTodo.overrideWithValue(todos[i]),
  ],
  child: const TodoItem(),
),
```

This allows us to use `const` when constructing `TodoItem` instead of passing the `todos[i]` in the constructor. This ensures that when we edit todos, only the impacted widgets rebuild, instead of the entire list of items.

Later on we can consume the todo from the `TodoItem` build method:

```dart
final todo = ref.watch(_currentTodo);
```

Comment: I see! So it is essentially possible to override a provider through ProviderScope in different parts of the widget tree. I missed that part in the example, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamically creating providers at runtime is an anti-pattern. Source: I'm the author of Riverpod.

Providers should purposefully be globals.
If you don't respect that, you could end up with memory leaks or break some of the upcoming debug tools.

The fact that providers are global is not a problem though.
Riverpod is built around that condition and offers various solutions to the problems you'll face when building applications using this strategy.

For example, if the very example you shared ([the official TODO example app](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/tree/master/examples/todos)), the example correctly does not rebuild the entire application when updating the list of todos.

I invite you to put a `print` statement inside the `TodoItem` widget ([here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/7aac5baa9a026332cebec17831494805bd5a014b/examples/todos/lib/main.dart#L239)). You'll see that when updating todos, only the corresponding `TodoItem` updates.

Comment: "Source: I'm the author of Riverpod."
kkkkkkkkk. Best answer ever!

Comment: What do you suggest in this scenario https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/download-button

Here the `DownloadController` created dynamically for every downloadable item
Similarly I created `StateNotifier` for every item in my project